# PHP REST Service Consumption in iOS 8 Swift

Tags: swift

I've seen RESTKit and Mantle in Github. They are designed in Objective-C. Objective-C is OK with the Swift. But I like to know about a framework provided by Apple or any third-party written in Swift itself for REST Service(GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into Agent -- Minimalistic Swift HTTP request agent for iOS and OS X https://github.com/hallas/agent
Inside there is a Agent.swift https://github.com/hallas/agent/blob/master/Agent/Agent.swift where you can find how GET/POST/PUT/DELETE works

Also take a look on Alamofire from creators of AFNetwork https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: We can extend the discussion to make the Question and Answer meaningful for programmers wanting to shift into iOS Swift. I think Igor Barinov can make some use cases where to use what for REST Service use.